# spark 3.2.1 Apache spark table incompatible data type with parquet

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, databricks-sql

Situation:

1. I get a parquet file generated for me every X amount of time.  Can't change the column type of the file, nor parquet schema.   Can't modify and rewrite the parquet to a new file location because it has to be picked up from there.  Process for generating the parquet file can't/won't be changed.
2. Using databricks with spark 3.2.1.  Trying to create a table that points to the parquet file in (1) using the following code

   ```
   create database if not exists sampledb;
   drop table if exists sampledb.table;
   create table sampledb.table (ID BIGINT, Column1 string) 
   using parquet
   OPTIONS(path='/path/to/parquet/');
   ```
3. I get the following error;

   ```
   com.databricks.sql.io.FileReadException: Error while reading file ........
   Parquet column cannot be converted. Column: [ID], Expected: LongType, Found: INT32
   ```

What data-type should i use when specifying the spark table schema so it can read parquet file?  I'm open to using scala, py-spark and/or python if needed.

Comment: BIGINT is an alias for LongType. Try the INT type.```create table sampledb.table (ID INT, Column1 string)```

Comment: thanks @OluwafemiSule that did it! can you please put it as an answer so i can accept it?

Comment: Glad that helped. I'll make an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BIGINT` is an alias for `LongType`.

The ID column in the parquet schema is defined as `int32`.

Use the `INT` type for the ID column.

```sql
drop table if exists sampledb.table;
create table sampledb.table (ID INT, Column1 string) 
using parquet
OPTIONS(path='/path/to/parquet/');
```